# ExpressJS req.logout Callback Not Called

Tags: express, passport.js, logout

I have an Express.js route to logout. For some reason the req.logout callback isn't called when I test the route. I know the callback isn't called because console.log doesn't print in the callback, and Chrome's dev tool network tab hangs. No HTTP response is sent. What's wrong? Thank you for any help.

```
app.get('/logout', (req, res, next) => {
  console.log('A');
  req.logout((error) => {
    console.log('B');
    if (error) {
      next(error);
    } else {
      res.redirect('/');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Unless you show a bit more no one can tell what's going on here. Can you show a bit more, a full route maybe?  And logout implementation?

Comment: I added the full route which is around my logout call. So far from my searches online I haven't found anyone with the same problem.

Comment: What is  `req.logout` ? Do you use Passport.JS or it is your custom implementation? And are you sure `req` is the name of your express instance? If not `req.get` does nothing.

Comment: I'm using Passport.js so I have `req.logout`. And I'm sorry, `app.get` is my route handler, I updated my code sample.

Comment: So, still the same error? How do you call the logout endpoint?

Comment: Still the same error. I have an UI button I'm using to trigger an HTTP request. I know I get to my route because I see a console.log print log. But the `req.logout` callback isn't called because I don't see a second console.log print log, and my Chrome dev tool network tab hangs without getting a HTTP response.

Comment: That means your PassportJS is not set up properly or you are missing something there.

Comment: The Passport.js strategy I'm using is `SamlStrategy`, can this be related to the issue?

Comment: Ok, taking a step back, I'm moving code from a monolith to a microservice. I've been trying to request logout from my microservice without luck. When I request logout from my monolith I'm able to do so. The monolith uses an older version of PassportJS as `req.logout` doesn't take a callback. This gives me more info to debug with. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: Not the strategy but the way it is implemented. If you want to get helped you should always try to expose as much information as possible because no one knows what's going on behind your text editor

Comment: I'm not sure the strategy is the issue. My controller logic above exits before the callback of `req.logout` is called. So my HTTP request in my frontend hangs as pending, because the HTTP response above is never sent from in the logout callback.

Comment: Actually, I see from my `MultiSamlStrategy` definition that I'm not defining a logout callback as is shown on [this](https://github.com/node-saml/passport-saml#configure-strategy-for-multiple-providers) Github.